# ListBox ContentControl Click Not Selecting Row

Tags: .net, wpf, listbox, contentcontrol

These items are in

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate> <DataTemplate>
```

The problem I have is the left click on the first ContentControl does not select the row
Left click the TextBlock does select the row

If I comment out the scrollViewer the it works.
So it appears the ScrollViewer is eating the click.
I am going to try moving the Visibility up to the ScrollView.

visabilityConverterReverse just returns Visible for false and Collapsed for true
when the row is selected i substitute in more characters of the same data

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"                                                         
            Text="{Binding Path=FieldDefApplied.FieldDef.DispName}"/>
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,0,0,0" Padding="0" MouseRightButtonDown="cc_CopyToClip" FontWeight="Normal"
        Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource visabilityConverterReverse}}"                                                    
        Content="{Binding Path=DispValueShortRunHighlight, Converter={StaticResource stringToXaml}}"/>
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" 
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="140">
    <ContentControl MouseRightButtonDown="cc_CopyToClip" 
        Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource bvc}}"
        Content="{Binding Path=DispValueRunHighlight, Converter={StaticResource stringToXaml}}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Just tried this in small sample and worked for me. Can you post small relevant code to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @RohitVats Hold tight as this is a massive amount of code with a lot of other stuff going on.   It may be that I have two ContentControl in that same Row and Column that are just visible opposite of each other.

Comment: Yeah likely problem is somewhere in it. Try to replicate it in small sample so that you can track it down easily. Big code is always a mess to dig into :)

Comment: @RohitVats It appears the ScrollView that is the problem.  Let me work on that.

Comment: @RohitVats If you want to post the ScrollViewer is the problem I will accept.  Or I will just delete.  You telling me it did not reproduce is was fixed the problem.

Comment: I have added the reason in the answer for this behaviour. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this in small sample with scrollViewer and was able to reproduce an issue.

`ScrollViewer` might be *eating up the MouseDown event* which doesn't get pass through to the ListBoxItem.

---

Like I said above here are the snapshots for raised events taken using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).

If you *click on first ContentControl*, it respond perfectly because **MouseDown events make its way to ListBoxItem perfectly hence selecting ListBoxItem**. Events flow is summarised below:

[image]

But in second case when you *click on ContentControl which is inside of ScrollViewer*, **ScrollViwer eats up the MouseDown event by handling it**. Here is the flow for second case:

[image]

Comment: Setting the Visibility directly on the ScrollViewer fixed it.  When it  is collapsed there is no surface to get hit.  If it eats the click on the selected item then no problem as the item is already selected.

Comment: Oh great. It might be issue in small sample that i have created where MouseDown event is getting eaten up and hence ListBoxItem never gets selected when i click on content control hosted inside scrollviewer. May be i missed some xaml code in there. But anyhow if it's solved for you than no issues. Have a good day..!! :)

Comment: Agree the ScrollViewer does eat the click.  But if ScrollViewer is collapsed there is no surface to hit.